# Webpack 4 and splitChunks - move all vendor code to a separate chunk except for the dynamically imported module

Tags: javascript, webpack, module, bundle, webpack-splitchunks

I have a project that looks like this:

- app.js
- module1.js
- node_modules

module1 is imported dynamically in app.js via `import(/* webpackChunkName: 'module1' */ '@path')`.

I'm trying to configure the splitChunks plugin so it would output:

1. app chunk including src code without dependencies and packages;
2. module1 chunk that includes both the source code AND required dependencies from node_modules for the dynamically imported module;
3. vendor chunk that includes the rest of the dependencies from node_modules;

What is the best way to do that?
The application has a single entry, which is app.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it with the following config. The key here is `chunks: inital` in vendor cachegroup.

```
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
      minSize: 0,
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: false,
        default: false,
        vendor: {
          chunks: 'initial',
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendor',
          reuseExistingChunk: true
        },
      },
    },
```